# SO-hosted example images for stack snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, images

Can we have some support for example images to be built into stack snippets? 
Images play an important role in many examples, but afaik the only way to use one is to get a link to the SO logo, or to some external source (I used WikiMedia in the past).

It would be nice if there is some way to get easy links to placeholder images. 
They can be small, fixed size and don't have to look awesome, as long as they have clear edges and maybe a pattern that shows scaling/distortion, so they can be cached rigorously.

In some cases inline images/data-urls could do the trick as well, but also then, I'd like to see this as a feature in Stack Snippets, rather than having to look those up somewhere.

Comment: You mean something like https://dummyimage.com/? Seems like a good idea but I have a feeling if people were going to use an image in their example they would just upload one and not notice the feature is there.

Comment: Yes, something like that. You could just use those links, but like any external resource, at some point they will not be available anymore, and the snippet will break. Doesn't have to be that elaborate, b.t.w, at least not to get started with. Apparently the code behind that website is MIT licensed PHP, so it's only a matter of integrating. ;-)

Comment: This is a good idea! And if some of the images showed free hand red circles, this would be purrfect!

Comment: If Tim Post doesn't draw a fresh free-hand circle every time I embed an image I would be very disappointed.

Comment: Pretty sure the sites run on ASP.NET, not PHP, but I doubt it would be that hard to write a dummy image service.

Comment: Maybe a unicorn-y variant of [placecats.com](https://placekats.com)/[placebear.com](https://placebear.com)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yep, ASP.NET MVC - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/253521

Comment: Probably not that hard for the great minds at SO, hence the wink in my comment. I think integrating it in the stack snippets UI in a nice way is the main challenge, but still worth it.

Comment: Why not just use images that you upload to Stack Exchange's imgur area? Sure, it would be convenient to have a set of common images, but why create a new area to contain images when one already exits, and has exited for SO/SE for a long time?

Comment: @Makyen Yes, imgur is arguably better than wikimedia to use as long as this feature isn't there, but random deeplink is easier than uploading something myself.  *"Sure, it would be convenient to have a set of common images"* probably answers your own question. I don't mind where and how exactly they are hosted or generated. I'm just asking for easy access to them, for a tool that makes it easier for me to ask or answer questions.

Comment: Related: [Example images for code and mark-up Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The other question is specifically about making other content than images available. My request is about integration in stack snippets. Also, that is an unanswered question of 4 years old. -.-

Comment: The code snippet that I include in that question shows an attempt to use an image resource that should be available to snippets.  I didn't just ask for resources other than images.  I do find it frustrating that it is unanswered and the one deleted answer that I did get didn't really help.